# Produce 2 side-by-side tables from tables as external files (source: xtable in R)

Tags: tables, spacing, r

Is it possible to put two tables next to each other, which are in separate .tex files, and added to the document via `\input`? If it's not, I could also create just the 'raw' contents of the tables, i.e. just the rows and columns by using the `content.only` command of xtable.

Assume I got the following table **TWO times**, saved as two separate tex files:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lYY}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$N_1$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$N_2$} \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$S_1$} &  0.14 & -1.243 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$S_2$} &  0.217 &  4.132 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$S_3$} &  7.350 & -9.913 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$S_4$} & 0.132 & 6.664 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Can I put these next to each other by using `input`? I know you need to utilize the `minipage` environment somehow, but I don't know if this works in combination with include. I could not make it work in some tests.

If include doesn't work, I might create just the content to put it inside the minipage environment at the right positions. Either way, please help me with the code. Thanks!

Comment: `\include` always makes a new page and is designed for including things like whole chapters. To input a fragment such as a table you want `\input`. You can input two tabular side by side using `\input` into the same `table` You do not need minipage

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Alright, but xtable in R (for making Latex tables out of R code) seems to produce only whole table environments OR just the rows without anything else. That's bad for making tabulars, because I'd have to edit the files manually.
Is it possible to use `input` somehow in the minipage environment? (also edited the Question. I meant input, my bad for calling it include)

Comment: you don't have to edit the files, TeX is a macro expansion language, and macros can be redefined.... (I may post an answer in a bit)  you can use `\input` more or less anywhere, but minipage won't obviously help (as you can not put a table environment in a minipage)

Comment: It would have helped if you had provided a complete working document showing all definitions (eg Y is not a standard column type) But we can use the example @Jubobs has provided now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it is possible.

Under the assumption that your .tex files each consists in some code of the form `\begin{table}\begin{tabular}{...} ... \end{tabular}\end{table}`, you can

- locally redefine the `table` environment to do nothing, and
- input that code inside a `subtable` environment; such an environment uses `minipage` internally, which means you don't have to use `minipage` explicitly.

Note that, in this specific case, you want to use `\input`, not `\include`; see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) for more details.

See my example below, in which I've defined a macro called `\insertmytabular`, for more automation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcommand\insertmytabular[3][.45]%
{%
    {% extra group to make the redefinition of table local
        \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{}{}
        \begin{subtable}[b]{#1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \input{#2}
            \caption{#3}
        \end{subtable}%
    }%
}

\begin{filecontents*}{tabularstuff.tex}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$N_1$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$N_2$} \\
\midrule 
$S_1$ &  0.14 & -1.243 \\ 
$S_2$ &  0.217 &  4.132 \\ 
$S_3$ &  7.350 & -9.913 \\ 
$S_4$ & 0.132 & 6.664 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \insertmytabular{tabularstuff}{first table}
    \hfill
    \insertmytabular{tabularstuff}{second table}
    \caption{two tables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** (answer to [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147895/produce-2-side-by-side-tables-from-tables-as-external-files-source-xtable-in-r/147898?noredirect=1#comment335695_147898)): in that case, define `\insertmytabular` as follows:

```
\newcommand\insertmytabular[3][.45]%
{%
    {% extra group to make the redefinition of table local
        \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{}{}
        \begin{subtable}[b]{#1\textwidth}
            \input{#2}
        \end{subtable}%
    }%
}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks about the missing `%` :)

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for. Saves me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: @Jubobs little follow-up question: What do I have to change in the macro if my tables are slightly more complicated, sthg like:
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption[short cap]{long cap} 
    \label{}
    {\normalsize
    \begin{tabular}{lYY}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}

Comment: @TomM See my edit.